# When is it correct to use symbols in place of variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, programming-languages

I'm new to Ruby and trying to get my head around some of its syntax.

Why does this code work with a variable for the exception object:

```
begin
  puts Dir::delete
rescue ArgumentError => e
  puts e.backtrace
end
```

but not with a symbol?

```
begin
  puts Dir::delete
rescue ArgumentError => :e
  puts e.backtrace
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbol is a value. In your example you need a variable to store the Error object. You usually use symbols as string constants.

For example, if you create a module with cardinal directions it is better to use the symbols `:north`, `:south`, `:east`, `:west` rather than the strings `"north"`, `"south"`, `"east"` and `"west"`.

Symbols are often used as keys in hashes:

```
my_hash = { a: 1, b: 7, e: 115 }
```

It's very useful to read ruby code on github for instance in order to understand when to use symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Because, as you write in the question itself, you need an Exception object, not a Symbol object.

In the rescue block you're accessing `backtrace` via the `e` object, which is of type `ArgumentException`, not of the type `Symbol`.

So what actually happens when the interpreter parses `:e` is, that indirectly a new `Symbol` object is created and its value is set to `:e`. It's like writing `23`, where a `Fixnum` object is indirectly created and its value is set to 23.

But a symbol itself can be stored in a variable:

```
some_var = :e
e = :e
```

Hope it's clear what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `e` is a variable where is stored the exception object and `:e` is a data type so it is kind of value.

some examples

```
# standard way of assign variable will work
e = ArgumentError.new 

# assign to data will not work
:e = ArgumentError.new
'e' = ArgumentError.new
 1 = ArgumentError.new
```

Answer (score 1):

Symbols in place of variable names - never (symbol is a value, name is a name. Apple and orange);

Variables in place of symbols - as you wish (as in `s = :name; puts params[s]`);

Symbols in place of strings - with care (if you create too many symbols, you might run into troubles).

Comment: Hey thanks but what is the value of writing `s = :name; puts params[s]` when you could write `s = 'name'; puts params[s]`?

Comment: @Arman: `s = 'name'` won't work if you have a hash like `{name: 'John'}`. The params object in rails is a special kind of hash, it eats both strings and symbols, but normal regular hashes distinct the two.

Comment: That's clear but one more question: how can a hash like `params` be defined?

Comment: Simply create an instance of [HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html).

Comment: Is HashWithIndifferentAccess a rails specific class? I couldn't create one in irb

Comment: It's in ActiveSupport. Try `require 'active_support/core_ext'` first.